# Notice: Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field in

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to setup recaptcha on my site. The captcha form is appearing but when I enter it in and submit, I get the following response from the server:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field in **the_location_of_the_php_file_containing_server_captcha_code.php** on line **6**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: recaptcha_response_field in **the_location_of_the_php_file_containing_server_captcha_code.ph** on line **7**
The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol)

I'm not sure what's going on. I'm pulling my hair out with this one. In the form which contains the captcha I've got this code:

```
    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "MY_PUBLIC"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
```

And in the file which the form action goes to I've got:

```
    require_once('location of captcha library');
    $privatekey = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    } else {
// Your code here to handle a successful verification
    }
```

Not sure what it could be. I followed the instructions on the captcha website exactly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible situations: Your form has the wrong method eg `<form method="POST">` or the input element with a name of `<input name="recaptcha_challenge_field">` doesn't exist or is being created by the `recaptcha_get_html()` function or even you're not wrapping your `recaptcha_check_answer()` in a check to see if you're dealing with a posted form via `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: The form is actually being submitted with jquery .post() having the data type as "JSON" instead of a traditional form action with post. That's still a post method, I thought. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, more than likely. Your usage of jQuery should have been mentioned.

Comment: doesn't seem to be the case. I switched to a normal form with action instead of the jquery post() method and it still didn't work. Same server response.

Comment: Confirm in your HTML source that there is a input field with the `name="recaptcha_challenge_field"` and `name="recaptcha_response_field"` prior to submitting the form, if not then there is probably something wrong with your implimentation of `recaptcha_get_html()` (ensuring it's within the `<form></form>` tags)

Comment: I've confirmed that both fields exist and the recaptcha_get_html() is inside the form tag.

Comment: All I can suggest is trying to diagnose $_POST with `var_dump($_POST)` at the start of the document and before you call `recaptcha_check_answer()`